# reading a file from s3 bucket with laravel getting error

Tags: amazon-s3, laravel-5

Im trying to get file from s3 bucket using `getObject`

```
 $s3 = AWS::createClient('s3');
        $file = $s3->getObject(array(
            'Bucket' => 'hotel4cast',
            'Key'    => $path->path,
            'SaveAs' => public_path()
        ));
```

I'm getting below error

Error executing

```
"GetObject" on "https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/filename.xlsx"; 
AWS HTTP error: Unable to open /var/www/html/laravel/public/ using mode r+: fopen(/var/www/html/laravel/public/): 
ailed to open stream: Is a directory
```

if i take `SaveAs` out and dump `$file` i get object of data, body, stream all that stuff but not sure what to do with that.

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out, there is bug in aws sdk,
i was able to get file to save by storing path in var before calling getObject

```
$r = fopen(public_path() . '/myfile.xlsx', 'wb');

$s3 = AWS::createClient('s3');
$file = $s3->getObject(array(
   'Bucket' => 'bucketname',
   'Key'    => $path->path,
   'SaveAs' => $r
));
```

Answer (score 0):

can you tell me that what exactly these equals too ? So, I can guide you accordingly.

```
$path->path = ???
public_path() = ???
```

**Edited**

your method params should be like this, you just passing the `saveAs` path but attaching the key name, So, add the `keyname` with `saveAs` path, it will be downloaded.

```
 $s3 = AWS::createClient('s3');
        $file = $s3->getObject(array(
            'Bucket' => 'hotel4cast',
            'Key'    => $path->path,
            'SaveAs' => public_path()."/filename.xlsx"
        ));
```

here are the examples of code, which I am using for uploading file and coping file

**for uploading**

```
    $result = $this->S3->putObject([
        'ACL' => 'public-read-write',
        'Bucket' => 'xyz', // REQUIRED
        'Key' => 'file.xlsx', // REQUIRED
        'SourceFile' => public_path()."/xlsx/file.xlsx",
    ]);
```

**for Coping from one bucket to another**

```
    $copy   =   $this->S3->copyObject(array(
                      'ACL' => 'public-read-write',
                      'Bucket' => 'xyz', // REQUIRED
                      'Key' => 'file.xlsx', // REQUIRED
                      'CopySource' => 'mybucketname/xlsx/file.xlsx,
                ));
```

but your file which is exists in s3 bucket should have permission to read. other wise it will give you error to `saveAs`, `copy` etc

here are multiple permissions, you can see here

```
'ACL' => 'private|public-read|public-read-write|authenticated-read|aws-exec-read|bucket-owner-read|bucket-owner-full-control',
```

Comment: Public_path() is just path to public folder of laravel project. And $path->path is path for s3 bucket where file is located, in this case it gets /foldername/filename.xlsx

Comment: I updated the answer, just add `filename.xlsx` with `public_path()` and check that you got the file or not

Comment: I forgot to mention I have tried that way also, it gives me same error

Comment: which Oprating system you are using ? if `Linux/Ubuntu/Debian` etc then try to give read/write (`chmod 775 -r ./public`) permission to your public folder and then tried my mentioned method

Comment: I got Ubuntu instance on Amazon ec2, permission should be good because I have upload form on site and files get uploaded to that folder just fine

Comment: as per my understanding, your file (s3 bucket) don't has the read/write permission. that can be reason try to upload another file with `'ACL' =>'public-read-write'` and try to `saveAs`

Comment: What is acl part? Do I put that before saveas option in getobject?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105860/discussion-between-qazi-and-vishal-desai).